# is it possible to place repeat block in classic email HTML template?

Tags: email, email-template, html

I am building an email template using HTML and I was wondering if I can place a repeat block in HTML to view a list of rows. 
I know if I use Visualforce template I can achieve my goal using apex: repeat, but I would like to know if it is possible using just HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce markup is only available in Visualforce email templates.  Hence, the answer is No.

But a Visualforce email template can be almost entirely HTML and in fact, shouldn't contain VF components with built in styling like `apex:pageBlock` so I'm not sure what the penalty is for using the VF template (unless the running user is Automated Process user where rendering can be problematic and VF components don;t work at all)